# The Collections in Java have limited capacity?

Tags: java, collections

i'm reading about collections, namely, [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html) in this moment, but i can't understand a part

> Each vector tries to optimize storage management by maintaining a capacity and a capacityIncrement. The capacity is always at least as large as the vector size; it is usually larger because as components are added to the vector, the vector's storage increases in chunks the size of capacityIncrement. An application can increase the capacity of a vector before inserting a large number of components; this reduces the amount of incremental reallocation.

I have been reading very little about collections in java, and the little I have seen I realize that they are dynamic, but until a moment I thought they were unlimited, I do not know if they are, this capacity and capacityIncrement confuse me, someone could explain me what they consist of please? :)

Comment: I was going to write an answer about this but it's explained in detail [here](https://interviewsansar.com/java-vector-time-complexity-and-how-vector-grows-in-java/)

Comment: Be aware that the `Vector` class is [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), as noted in its Javadoc. Supplanted by the `ArrayList` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add as many elements to a collection as you please.  They are unlimited in that sense.

Some collections have an internal *capacity*, which describes how many elements the collection can hold *without* allocating more memory or rebuilding its internal data structures.

By setting the capacity correctly in advance, you can ensure that the collection doesn't need to allocate any more memory than necessary, or spend extra time rebuilding its data structures.  Setting capacity is about optimizing performance, not how many elements you can ever add to a collection.

(Finally, as a side note, I recommend noticing how `Vector` has effectively been replaced by `ArrayList` for decades, and how you should really never use it anymore.)

Comment: how can i set the capacity?

Comment: That varies for each collection, but it's mostly set by constructors that accept a capacity and methods named `ensureCapacity`.  That's certainly the case for `Vector`.

Comment: oh, now i've just read the last part, so i'm spending time trying to understand the vector in depth?

Comment: Be aware that `Vector` is synchronized

Comment: As far as I'm aware Collections with an internal array aren't "unlimited", they have a hard cap of Integer.MAX -1 (round about). Java doesn't allow larger arrays, even if the memory would be available

Comment: @Tom: I am comfortable calling that unlimited for realistic purposes.  I also don't bother to mention when the memory required to store a piece of data is limited by the number of atoms in the universe.  (The cap on arrays also varies per VM implementation; I've seen other bounds like MAX-3 or MAX-8.)

Comment: While `Vector` is synchronized, simply wrapping an `ArrayList` in `Collections.synchronizedList` is just as effective.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Or just as ineffective, as the case may be. :-)